# Why arrows keys do not work inside icefaces dataTable textEntry inside cell

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, icefaces

I use icefaces 3 `ace:dataTable` and inside column I use `ace:textEntry.` When I try to change value inside `ace:textEntry` I noticed arrows keys do not work. So it is not possible to change cursor position inside column `textEntry` using left, right keys. Why?

```
<ace:dataTable value="#{myBean.items}" var="row" 
               paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top" rows="5">
   <ace:column headerText="Item">
      <ace:textEntry value="#{row.itemValue}"/>
   </ace:column>
</ace:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

The arrows key do not work because `ace:dataTable` uses `paginator`. After removing `paginator="true"` arrows keys works again.